# Can we pass variables by reference in JavaScript Function?

Tags: javascript

I am calculating row and column of a given point by javascript function.

To achieve this I have to declare global variables

```
var global_row;
var global_col;
```

Here is function body

```
function calculate_city_row_col(cur_city_id)
{
    var r = 565;
    var c = 1;
    var max_city_id = 159895;
    do{
        if((r%2) == 0) c++;
        max_city_id -= r;
        r--;
    }
    while(cur_city_id <= max_city_id)

    //Saving Result in seperate row and column
    global_row = r + 1;                                 //Global Variable
    global_col = c + (cur_city_id - (max_city_id + 1)); //Global Variable
}
```

Here is function call

```
var city_id = 1244;
calculate_city_row_col(city_id);
var city_row = global_row;
var city_col = global_col;
```

Is there anyway to directly pass local variables? (without using global variables)

like this

```
calculate_city_row_col(cur_city_id, city_row_ref, city_col_ref);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return an object:

```
function calculate_city_row_col(cur_city_id)
{
    var r = 565;
    var c = 1;
    var max_city_id = 159895;
    do{
        if((r%2) == 0) c++;
        max_city_id -= r;
        r--;
    }
    while(cur_city_id <= max_city_id)

    return {
        row: r + 1,
        col: c + (cur_city_id - (max_city_id + 1))
    };
}

var rowAndCol = calculate_city_row_col(1244);
var city_row = rowAndCol.row;
var city_col = rowAndCol.col;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can we pass variables by reference in JavaScript Function

No. JavaScript is purely pass-by-value (the value passed when you pass an object around is an *object reference*, but it's still a value).

Your options are:

1. Have the function return an object (or array)

   ```
   function calculate_city_row_col(cur_city_id)
   {
       var r = 565;
       var c = 1;
       var max_city_id = 159895;
       do{
           if((r%2) == 0) c++;
           max_city_id -= r;
           r--;
       }
       while(cur_city_id <= max_city_id)

       //Saving Result in seperate row and column
       return {
           row: r + 1,
           col: c + (cur_city_id - (max_city_id + 1))
       };
   }
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   var result = calculate_city_row_col(someCityId);
   console.log(result.row);
   console.log(result.col);
   ```
2. Have the function accept a reference to an object (or array) that it updates

   ```
   function calculate_city_row_col(cur_city_id, result)
   {
       var r = 565;
       var c = 1;
       var max_city_id = 159895;
       do{
           if((r%2) == 0) c++;
           max_city_id -= r;
           r--;
       }
       while(cur_city_id <= max_city_id)

       //Saving Result in seperate row and column
       result.row = r + 1;
       result.col = c + (cur_city_id - (max_city_id + 1));
   }
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   var result = {};
   calculate_city_row_col(someCityId);
   console.log(result.row);
   console.log(result.col);
   ```

Barring a strong reason to go with #2 in a specific situation, #1 is usually the best option. For instance, if you were calling this function thousands of times in a tight loop, there *might* be a justification for reusing a single object (by passing it in) instead of creating a new object every time.